# SwiftUI: No ObservableObject of type Y found, where Y is a subclass of an ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, observableobject

SwiftUI errors like this appear frequently on StackOverflow:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Foo found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Foo may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

The answer is always to pass a `Foo` instance to a view's `environmentObject()` function. However, this does not appear to work when passing a *subclass* of `Foo` to `environmentObject()`.

### Foo.swift

```
class Foo: ObservableObject {
    func doSomething() { ... }
}
```

### Bar.swift

```
class Bar: Foo {
    override func doSomething() { ... }
}
```

### Views.swift

```
struct BrokenView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var foo: Foo

    var body: some View { ... }
}

struct WorkingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var foo: Bar

    var body: some View { ... }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        BrokenView().environmentObject(Bar())   // No ObservableObject of type Foo found...
        WorkingView().environmentObject(Bar())  // OK
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use `ObservableObject` subclasses as environment objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1) - `EnvironmentObject` matches injection by explicit type.

```
var body: some View {
    BrokenView().environmentObject(Bar() as Foo)   // OK
    WorkingView().environmentObject(Bar())  // OK
}
```

Comment: That’s cumbersome, but I’ll take it! Why does that work?